# Angular 12 http request returning undefined parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

`In my service.ts file, I am calling a method that makes an http request to the following API:`
users/1111/state/2222
`Where 1111 is the userId and 2222 is the stateId.`

service.ts method call

```
public getParams(userId: number, stateId: number): Observable<MyModel> {
   return this.get(`users%2F${userId}final-rosters%2F${stateId}`)
     .pipe(map(response => response.body));
 }
```

In my component.ts file. I am calling the method like so:

```
public getUser(
    userId: number,
    stateId: number,
  ): void {
    this.myService.getParams(userId, stateId)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.myModel.next(result);
        console.log('GET DATA ', result);
      });
  }
```

In my inspect tools, I am getting the following:
http://10.1.9.141:9999/api/elections/undefined/final-rosters/undefined

I am having a bit of trouble converting the actual url path into a path that takes on the 2 parameters.

Comment: In the code you've given the service method is called getParams but in your code you call ... this.myService.getUsers - apart from that your code looks fine - please console.log the values every step of the way ... are userId and stateId undefined when passed to getUser? the URL you give suggests that these 2 values are undefined. Are they undefined every step of the journey these 2 variables take? ... console.log to find out

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your service URL properly :

```
public getParams(userId: number, stateId: number): Observable<MyModel> {

   const configUrl = 'users/${userId}/final-rosters/${stateId}'
   return this.get<MyModel>(configUrl), { observe: 'response' });

 }
```